# Catching a promise without reject

Tags: javascript

I was going through [express-async-handler](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler/blob/master/index.js) code

```
const asyncUtil = fn =>
function asyncUtilWrap(...args) {
  const fnReturn = fn(...args)
  const next = args[args.length-1]
  return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)
}

module.exports = asyncUtil
```

Here they have used .catch without rejecting a promise and created a promise without using a promise constructor (`new Promise(resolve, reject)`)

We use the above snippet of code like this

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
express.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const bar = await foo.findAll();
    res.send(bar)
}))
```

Can someone help me in comprehending what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`fnReturn` **might** be a promise, which would mean that the promise created with `Promise.resolve` would adopt it. The adopted promise might throw an error which needs catching

Comment: updated the question. Can you please answer in slightly more details?

Comment: @anny123 — There's no detail to add. It's a very simple concept.

Comment: Can this statement `  return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)` same as  `return Promise.then(fnReturn).catch(next)`  and  `return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).reject(next)`

Comment: The `Promise` constructor function isn't a promise (it is a tool to make promises with), so it doesn't have a `then` method. `catch` and `reject` are completely different things. So no, all three of those bits of code are different.

Answer (score 0):

const fnReturn = fn(...args)

Here fn might be returning a promise which is getting passed as parameter to Promise.resolve and every time below code will return an resolved promise even if fnReturn throws an error and in this catch block may not be executed on rejection.

And more over Promise.resolve or Promise.reject is an another approach to return resolvedPromise value or rejected promise value.

please find below snippet to understand it better.

```js
let a = Promise.resolve(13);
a.then((value)=>{console.log(value)});
```

More over to add on to this foo.findAll() returns a promise which we consume it using async await based on latest ES6 features and if you don't mind consume await under an try block so that if any error is encountered then it can be captured in catch block.

```js
try{
const bar = await foo.findAll()
}
catch(exception){
  console.log(exception);
}
```

Comment: Can this statement `return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)` same as return `Promise.then(fnReturn).catch(next)` and return `Promise.resolve(fnReturn).reject(next)`

Comment: Then can't be refered over Promise , it can be refered only on resolved promise and catch block on rejected promise , thats why we can't represent Promise.then(fnReturn).catch(next) in exchange of return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)

Answer (score 0):

> created a promise without using a promise constructor

I saw something wrong in previous answer : **fnReturn doesn’t have to be a Promise itself**. It even has nothing to do with it. As specified in documentation :

> The resolve function returns either a new promise resolved with the passed argument, or the argument itself if the argument is a promise produced by this constructor.

[ecma.org](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve)

Which means, in other word, that argument passed to `Promise.resolve()` can be a synchrone function, which will be wrapped inside a new Promise. So that answer your first question : they don’t use Promise constructor because they don’t have to, javascript is doing it for them (like in a `try{…} catch{…}` function).

> Here they have used .catch without rejecting a promise

When trying to figure out something, it is always interesting to play a bit around with your code. Let’s take a look at the following snippet:

```js
// Original code
const asyncUtil = fn =>
function asyncUtilWrap(...args) {
  const fnReturn = fn(...args);
  const next = args[args.length-1];
  return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next);
};

// Simulation
const req = {
  url: "random"
};

const res = {
  html: "rendered"
};

function next(err) {
  alert(err.message);
  return
}

asyncUtil(async (req, res, next) => {
    // throw new Error("An error occured here");
    const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(() => {resolve("Result of async function")}, 1000);
    });
    
    alert(result);
})(req, res, next);
```

This code intend to simulate an express environment… well, at least in the way we are interested in. I defined `req` and `res` as 2 fake objects, and `next()` to just display our error, if any. `asyncUtil()` will launch a function that resolve after 1 second, and display its result.

First run of the snippet should give the following result :

[image: First result : everything went good]

Notice the 3 commented lines. Here, everything went fine, and we got our result displayed. So what happens exactly here.

`const fnReturn = fn(...args);` This line assign our async function to fnReturn (`fnReturn = async (req, res, next) => {. . .}`). So when we call `Promise.resolve(fnReturn)`, what it actually does is wrapping it inside a Promise like this :

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(fnReturn);
});
```

Once completed, it will asynchronously return the result of `fnReturn` to callback.

Now our promise can only resolve, meaning it doesn’t have a reject on itself. But that doesn’t mean errors can’t occur. If you try to uncomment the following line :

```
throw new Error("An error occured here");
```

What we’ll do is throwing a fake error at the beginning of our function. Notice the result when running this :

[image: Error thrown]

Our regular script wasn’t executed (it breaks after an error), and we moved to our `next()` function !

Our Promise doesn’t have any error handler, but if an error is thrown, even outside a `reject()`, it’ll still propagate. Here, the Promise can’t resolve as it is broke in process, and our `catch()` will be able to block the exception, avoiding your whole code shutting down.

Hope it was clear enough, feel free to ask if anything wasn’t understandable !